# How will Windows 8 Explorer extensibility model look like?

Tags: c#, native, windows-8

Is there anything known yet about a possible extensibility model for Windows Explorer in Windows 8? Will it likely be C++ only or will .NET extensions be supported too?

Comment: Maybe if we're lucky, it won't be.  (Only half-kidding...)

Comment: Probably exactly the same, given that the Metro desktop doesn't use Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending explorer would be a desktop-only story.  Metro style applications cannot modify the system.  They can only interact with it through contracts.

That means explorer extension will remain the same as it was in Windows 7.

Comment: I thought you could still use WinRT in desktop apps. Is that not the case?

Comment: You can use some portions of WinRT from the desktop.  I can't think of any WinRT APIs that are involved with Explorer extensions, however.  Are you just wondering if you can use WinRT APIs from an explorer extension?

Comment: Your answer just seemed to suggest that because Metro couldn't do it, it couldn't be done -- i.e., that WinRT is only usable from Metro. But that didn't match with my previous understanding -- as far as I understand it, Explorer *could* expose a WinRT extensibility model, and non-Metro .NET apps could use it, if there was any reason for MS to throw the resources at building such a thing. (Just trying to clarify my understanding.)

Comment: "That means explorer extension will remain the same as it was in Windows 7." So that means C++? (I know very little about Win Explorer extensibility in current versions of Windows.)

Comment: @Borek, I'm no explorer extensibility expert, but I believe that is true (C++).  

Joe, Yes, Explorer could theoretically expose a WinRT extensibility model.  Most parts of the OS could theoretically be done as WinRT objects.  But it isn't right now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can access the Windows Runtime through multiple languages. Its possible that Windows Explorer extensibility model and Win32/64 API can be part of that too.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-874T